# EXEC_BAD_ACCESS on applicationWillEnterForeground in iOS3 but not iOS4

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have my application working great on my iOS **4.3.3** iPhone 3GS. When I test the app on a **3.1.3** iPhone 3G, the program crashes right after the splash image is shown. The debugger points to the last command of my root view controller's `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSLog(@"awakeFromNib");
    NSLog(@"applicationWillEnterForeground listened");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object: nil];
}
```

.

```
2011-08-09 15:56:24.585 AppName[4401:207] awakeFromNib
2011-08-09 15:56:24.602 AppName[4401:207] applicationWillEnterForeground listened
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
```

Is there something special about iOS 3's awaking/sleeping that I should know that would help me work around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the identifier `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` is pointing to an externally defined string that only exists on iOS 4 or later. On iOS 3 and earlier, it will evaluate to nil; thus, you are passing in nil for a notification name, which is why adding the observer is crashing.

You can fix this in two ways. You could directly use the string value of the notification's name in your code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self 
 selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
 name:@"UIApplicationWillEnterForeground" // might not be correct
 object:nil];
```

I'm not sure if that's what it is, you'll have to check the docs or use NSLog to be exactly sure of it.

A better option is to check the value of the identifier first, and only add a listener if it is supported:

```
if (UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self 
     selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
     name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
     object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the iOS Developer library:

> `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`
>
> Posted shortly before an application leaves the background state on
>   its way to becoming the active application. The object of the
>   notification is the UIApplication object. There is no userInfo
>   dictionary.
>
> Availability
>
> **Available in iOS 4.0 and later**.

This probably causes the EXEC_BAD_ACCESS. Does it crash if you remove that line of code?

Comment: Removing the line fixes it, but how do I simulate this event in iOS 3? I want the table view to refresh every time the user opens the app. Facebook does this. It updates your news feed whenever it's opened.

Comment: Notification names are strings, listening for an unsupported one won't crash your app, it will simply never get notified.

Comment: I created a workaround by using `applicationDidBecomeActive` instead. I just had to be careful differentiating `didBecomeActive` and `willEnterForeground`. Both are fired at nearly the same times, except `willEnterForeground` will not fire the *first* time the app boots up.